# Count repeating occurrences in existing table

Tags: arrays, excel, match, repeat

I have some 15 items which I wish to count how many times it repeats over a series of time. This is highlighted by 1 in that time period. As per the attached pic, the blue area is the data and the yellow is the result that I wish to obtain.

E.g. In occurrence 5, this repeats current record - 1 three times, current record - 2 two times etc. I also do not want to count the current wekks item twice as per the Observation item 14. The results in the yellow have been calculated manually, and the only alternative is to do individual IF statements based upon my knowledge...

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

Is there a formula to do this automatically? I have tried to work with arrays and matching items to check for repeats but cannot work it out.

**Update for Clarification:** In the Current Occurrence 5 - Obs 1, 6 and 15 came up in Occurrence 4 (Repeats Current -1 or Occurrence 4 - three times), Obs 5 and 8 came up in Occurrence 3 (Repeats Current -2 or Occurrence 4 - two times). (Occurrences are just points in time. Observations might be people having been observed doing something - the number of times is irrelevant, it is just a true or false outcome)

Looking at Occurrence 4, Obs 6 and 9 (Repeats Current -3) or Occurrence 1 two times (my bad I only specified 1 times which might have caused confusion).

I would like the formula to stop searching for prior occurrences once the next recent one has been found eg Obs 14 in Occurrence 3 should stop looking once it finds a repeat in Occurrence 2.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Also it is unclear how your data is converted into the results. Explain the logic behind that.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Luuklag. I hope I have provided additional information to assist in providing a response.

Comment: So to get this right. In oc.2 the repeat -1 value should be 2, as obs 11 and 14 match 1 below. Also, is your data always just 1's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use intermediate calculated cells, which you can hide later if you wish.

Insert 15 columns (1 for each observation) between observations and repeats.

In the first inserted cell create a formula for an individual repeated observation:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(B3),B3=B4)
```

i.e. To be counted as a repeat, the observation must be a number AND the same as the cell immediately below it.

Duplicate this formula horizontally so it calculates across for all 15 observations.

Then create a formula to the right to count the matching observations

```
=COUNTIF(R3:AF3,TRUE)
```

Now duplicate the formulas down for all the occurrences.

For current-2 you can reference the cell directly below and to the left, and duplicate this across and down.

For clarity, I have left out your last requiremnet, to stop searching once a match is found. To do this you will need to expand the intermediate formula to take this into account.

[image: Example calculation]

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Edward's answer I used the following formula as intermediate formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C7);C7=C8;C8=C9;C9=C10);"-3";IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C7);C7=C8;C8=C9);"-2";IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C7);C7=C8);"-1";"")))
```

Then use `Countif(R3:AF3;"-3")` to count the number of -3.

By starting the If constraints at -3 and working your way back, the formula stops automatically when the last match is found.